# Make interpreter execute faster

Tags: optimization, interpreter, execution

I've created an interprter for a simple language. It is AST based (to be more exact, an irregular heterogeneous AST) with visitors executing and evaluating nodes. However I've noticed that it is extremely slow compared to "real" interpreters. For testing I've ran this code:

```
i = 3
j = 3
has = false
while i < 10000
     j = 3
     has = false
     while j <= i / 2
          if i % j == 0 then
              has = true
          end
          j = j+2
     end
     if has == false then
          puts i
     end
     i = i+2
end
```

In both ruby and my interpreter (just finding primes primitively). Ruby finished under 0.63 second, and my interpreter was over 15 seconds.

I develop the interpreter in C++ and in Visual Studio, so I've used the profiler to see what takes the most time: the evaluation methods.
50% of the execution time was to call the abstract evaluation method, which then casts the passed expression and calls the proper eval method. Something like this:

```
Value * eval (Exp * exp)
{
   switch (exp->type)
   {
   case EXP_ADDITION:
        eval ((AdditionExp*) exp);
        break;

    ...
   }
}
```

I could put the eval methods into the Exp nodes themselves, but I want to keep the nodes clean (Terence Parr saied something about reusability in his book).

Also at evaluation I always reconstruct the Value object, which stores the result of the evaluated expression. Actually Value is abstract, and it has derived value classes for different types (That's why I work with pointers, to avoid object slicing at returning). I think this could be another reason of slowness.

How could I make my interpreter as optimized as possible? Should I create bytecodes out of the AST and then interpret bytecodes instead? (As far as I know, they could be much faster)

Here is the source if it helps understanding my problem: [src](https://github.com/LPeter1997/OTZ1interpreter)

Note: I haven't done any error handling yet, so an illegal statement or an error will simply freeze the program. (Also sorry for the stupid "error messages" :))

The syntax is pretty simple, the currently executed file is in OTZ1core/testfiles/test.txt (which is the prime finder).

I appreciate any help I can get, I'm really beginner at compilers and interpreters.

Comment: What are the new durations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility for a speed-up would be to use a function table instead of the switch with dynamic retyping. Your call to the typed-*eval* is going through at least one, and possibly several, levels of indirection. If you distinguish the typed functions instead *by name* and give them identical signatures, then pointers to the various functions can be packed into an array and indexed by the type member.

```
value (*evaltab[])(Exp *) = {  // the order of functions must match
    Exp_Add,                   // the order type values
    //...
};
```

Then the whole switch becomes:

```
evaltab[exp->type](exp);
```

1 indirection, 1 function call. Fast.